# Python switching between routines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a python program where I have three routines that need to switch between each other including a main loop, set up as follows:

pseudo-code:

```
main routine: 
   run routine, 
   while running:
    if obtained signal A run routine A, 
    else if obtained signal B run routine B

routine A: 
  run routine, 
  while running:
  if obtain signal B, run routine B, 
   else if completed with no signal run main
  else if no signal, just keep running

routine B: 
  run routine, 
  while running
  if obtain signal A, run routine A, 
  else if completed with no signal run main.
```

Where signal could sent by a handler that sets a variable that has an associated Lock on it. No two routines need to run simultaneously.

I was thinking of using non-preemptive threads, and wondering  if there exists a way to do non-preemptive threading python where threads can specifically yield to another target thread? I found [Yarn](http://sifter.org/~simon/yarn/about.html), but I don't know if that solves the problem. In addition, I was wondering if there is better way to accomplish this, maybe using co-routines instead?

Comment: Why do routine A and B need to call main again? It looks like main is already sitting and waiting for signals

Comment: I didn't mean for them to call main. Since I only want one running at a time.  Let's say A is running and finishes with no signal for B. I want it to yield to main which was suspended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
from random import choice

get_signal_somehow = lambda: choice(["A", "B"])

def main():
    A = routine_a()
    B = routine_b()
    signal = get_signal_somehow()
    while True:
        if signal == 'A':
            signal = next(A)
        elif signal == 'B':
            signal = next(B)

def routine_a():
    #do stuff
    if get_signal_somehow() == 'B':
        yield 'B'
    else:
        yield 'A'

def routine_b():
    #do stuff
    if get_signal_somehow() == 'A':
        yield 'A'
    else:
        yield 'B'
```

Comment: I think `signal =` should be inside the `while True`

Comment: It could be, but I did it intentionally outside, so that the next signals get determined by the other routines.

Comment: I was just thinking that `get_signal_somehow()` would wait like `socket.accept()`. Otherwise, the while loop will keep looping on the same signal value

Comment: Why do you need the iter  around the generator ?

Comment: @dylan7 If you "call" the function `routine_a()` you enter at the top. You need the iterator to set up the *pick-up-where-I-left-off* behavior using `for/next` (or in this case, `iter()/next()`). See http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf for FMTYEWTK about generators.

Comment: Maybe add:  `def get_signal_somehow(): import random; return random.choice(('A', 'B'))`

Comment: @AustinHastings They are actually right, `iter` is not needed.